# CodeIgniter with Wiredesignz HMVC routing

Tags: codeigniter, routes, hmvc

I am using HMVC and created a module called user. Inside modules/user/config directory, I have routes.php, using the same format as application/config/routes.php.

In application/config/routes.php I have the following route:

`$route['login'] = 'user/login';`

This works great, buit when I move it to application/modules/user/config/routes.php, it does not work. I get a 404 error.

According to HMVC docs (`https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc`), you have to create routes as follows:

`$route['module_name'] = 'controller_name';`

This means I will have to do it like this:

`$route['user'] = 'user';`

This causes the 404, however, even if I did not get the 404, this is not quite what I have in mind. I still want to keep my routing to work as /login goes to user/login.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Anybody with any ideas here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same exact problem as you, unfortunately the way Wiredesignz created the extension it requires that the path start with the module name itself if you put the routes file inside the module itself. That is the only way it will look at the routes file if it is placed inside a module. With that said it already knows the module name at that point, so you need to simply specify the controller and method that you want it to route to. So in your routes.php file inside of your module config directory, if you put this:

```
$route['yourmodule/some-route'] = "yourcontroller/yourmethod";
```

or in other words:

```
$route['user'] = 'user/login';
```

That would work I believe. However I still wanted more than this. I wanted to be able to use routes that may or may not have the module name. Due to this I had to extend the module to make this happen, and you can find the work I did here if this helps:

https://github.com/brianwozeniak/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

This would then allow you to use the route you wanted such as:

```
$route['login'] = 'user/login';
```

Even with that routes.php placed inside the module's config directory.

Comment: Thank you @Bigwebmaster. I will look into your fork of HMVC and see if I can make it work on my site. Would be awesome. Once I had a cahnce to check it out, I'll upvote/accept if need be. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, @Bigwebmaster, it works 100% for me too. Have a great day!

Comment: Hi, @Bigwebmaster it works well, but there is something you might want to look at: if you want to call a controller/function that is not linked to a particular route, it gives you a 404 error. Chances are you might need to call functions that are not bound to a route at some stage or another.

Comment: By default I made it so that routes are not valid unless specified. In the documentation I mention that as well, but basically if you go into routes.php and change: protected static $remove_default_routes = TRUE; to FALSE that should allow default route to work everywhere.

Comment: I also recently made so that controllers/methods can be called internally via other modules even if the route isn't explicitly specified, although, I haven't done much testing there so it is possible that its not working correctly.

Comment: Hi @Bigwebmaster, I saw that after I posted my comment; sorry for the mis-reporting.

Comment: Hi @Brian, are you planning on making this solution of yours compatible with CI3 and the latest Wiredesignz code for CI3?

Comment: Hi @Brian. Just checking up on this. Any chance you will make your fork work with latest Wiredesignz and CI3?

Comment: @KobusMyburgh, unfortunately, I have no plans to update the fork. I have since moved on from CI to Laravel.

Comment: Brian, thanks for responding. It's a pity, but good luck in Laravel. I am also starting to dabble there, but still firmly routed in CI.